# aspx pages not working after adding application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i have webapplication. In my master page i have few link buttons which are as below

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="link1" runat="server" OnClick="linkAge_Click">Age</asp:LinkButton>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="link2" runat="server"  OnClick="linkName_Click">Name</asp:LinkButton>
```

In my Visual studio i have seperate folder called Age and Name and under those there are default.aspx.

on click event of link button i have this code

```
protected void linkAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Redirect("/Age/");
    }

 protected void linkName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Redirect("/Name/");
    }
```

In IIS i added Application called "Test" and then added all code inside it

When i browse i get to master page as http://localhost:80/Test

When i click on link "Age" the url Changes to http://localhost:80/Age

I expected it to be http://localhost:80/Test/Age

What is wrong that i am doing? Can i achieve this without using any code changes.

Comment: It doesn't see "Test" as your master page. Try editing your redirect code to "/Test/Age/" and see the result.

Comment: @Apollo offcourse that will work but as i said i dont wish to change in code

Comment: I see. There are other ways to perform what you asked but they require changes in the code. I'll look around for other options. If "Test" folder is not under root directory, this kind of confusion might happen. Did you check that?

Comment: The best way to do this is adding routing rules to your global.asax page see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use http://localhost/Test/  (with slash in the end) link in to Your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a tilde (~) to get URLs relative to application root:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Age/");
```

BTW: Why do you need to have the redirect behind a post-back? You could use `<asp:HyperLink>` instead

Comment: only if you are on Windows Server: deploy your application as a Web Site, rather than a Web Application

Comment: i cannot have website under another website hence i added application

Answer (score 0):

Like we do this in mvc to get path from root - Url.Content("~\Action\")

In web form -

```
    protected void linkAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/Age/"));
    }
```

You got to think like this i think.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using only the `/Age/` path, with nothing to indicate that you're using a relative path. For code managed by IIS, you'd use `~/Age/Whatever` to indicate that you intend to go to `Age` relative to `Test`.